# Angular component in wicket panel

Tags: angularjs, wicket, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need your help again!

I'm working on getting an angular component (ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker) to load in a wicket component that is loaded outside of my angular code.

Here's what it looks like currently

**HTML from Wicket**

```
<span class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="">
    <div class="input-append">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Date/Time Value" class="input-large" data-ng-model="data.storedValue" required date-time-input="MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a">
      <button type="button" class="btn"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
    </div>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.storedValue" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '.dropdown-toggle', minView: 'minute', minuteStep: 1 }"></datetimepicker>
  </ul>
</span>
```

**Javascript that runs to compile angular**

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['app', 'ui.bootstrap']);
var selector = this.selector;
$injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    var element = $compile(angular.element(selector))($rootScope);
    element.scope().$apply();
    angular.element(selector).scope().$apply();
});
```

`app` is my angular app module.

This effectively renders the component and the drop down appears, but the dates are not populated. [image: As seen in this image]

I've tried several other configurations, but either it made things worse or didn't help at all. Ask questions and I'll answer as best I can!

**Edit**
Also I'm getting a bunch of errors in my console which will probably be helpful :P

- Error: Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <- dropdownToggleDirective
- Circular dependency: $animator <- ngRepeatDirective
- Circular dependency: ngShowDirective
- Error: Syntax Error: Token ',' not a primary expression at column 16 of the expression [changeView('', , $event)] starting at [, $event)].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course right after I posted this I figured out what I was doing wrong...

The javascript portion should have looked like...

```
var $injector = angular.element(document).injector();
var selector = this.selector;
$injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    var element = $compile(angular.element(selector))($rootScope);
    element.scope().$apply();
    angular.element(selector).scope().$apply();
});
```

I needed to get the injector from my main app rather than build a new one. Once I did that it was able to build the calendar. It led to a ton of other problems, but at least the component is rendering!